# is it possible to prepend a character to every line of terminal output, for every command?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, urxvt

Is it possible?

For example, say I want to run the command `ll`:

My output would look something like this:

```
josh@zeitgeist ~ ll
total 41148
drwxr-xr-x 42 josh josh     4096 Aug  4 22:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Jul  9 21:18 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 josh josh  3523718 Jul 11 00:17 2017-07-11-001710_3840x2160_scrot.png
```

but I want it to look like this:

```
josh@zeitgeist ~ ll
XXXtotal 41148
XXXdrwxr-xr-x 42 josh josh     4096 Aug  4 22:52 ./
XXXdrwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Jul  9 21:18 ../
XXX-rw-rw-r--  1 josh josh  3523718 Jul 11 00:17 2017-07-11-XXX001710_3840x2160_scrot.png
```

I already know about using `PS1='XXX'` to change the prompt; is there a way to change every line of the output that gets displayed, specifically in the terminal(not changing the output and putting it in a file)?

I would like to do this to have a unified line of characters going down the left side of my terminal.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Are you trying to easily tell your terminals apart?

Comment: `I would like to do this to have a unified line of characters going down the left side of my terminal` this is not clear, why would you want that?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do it with `sed`:

```
ll | sed 's/./XXX&/'
```

Comment: I'm been using sed for years. Previous to find this answer just now, I've had complicated functions perform while read loops. This sed 'trick' is utterly amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Prepend `XXX`to all lines including empty lines.

```
ll | sed 's/^/XXX/'
```

Edit:
After changing your PS1 you can invoke the solution for all commands using

```
bash | sed 's/^/XXX/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this I suppose:

```
while read; do echo "xxx $REPLY"; done < <(ls -l)
```

Not really sure what the purpose of this would be though.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ ll|awk '$0="XXX"$0'
```